# Parsing data and displaying it in different Fragments using AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, xml-parsing, android-asynctask

I'm creating an app that parses data from a URL, separates the data into different categories and then displays the data into different ListView in different fragments. I've successfully parsed the data, but I'm having problems to display the information. It's a little bit complicated: my app has 6 fragments (using SwipeViews) and each Fragment will display a part of the data (List). From a class ParseManager, which I'm extending to AsyncTask, I'm doing all the stuff (parsing, getting the Lists, etc).  The MainActivity executes the AsyncTask, and what I want to do is to send the data that I've collected in AsyncTask and send it to the different Fragments. The problem is the communication between the Fragments and the data, since the fragments are created in the method onCreateView() and the data is received after the view is created. This is the class that does all the work

```
public class ParseManager extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void>{
    static ArrayList<Item> news=new ArrayList<Item>();
    static ArrayList<Item> items=new ArrayList<Item>();
    private static String FEED_URL="some url";
    public int ready=0;
    Message msg;

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      Log.d("TASK","TASK FINISHED....");
     return;
   }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
    Log.d("TASK","TASK IS BEING PROCESSED....");
    loadXML();
    return null;
}

public void loadXML(){
    try{
        URL url=new URL(FEED_URL);
        HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(1000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1500);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream=conn.getInputStream();
        XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser xmlParser=factory.newPullParser();
        xmlParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        xmlParser.setInput(stream,null);
        items=(ArrayList<Item>) XmlFeedParser.parser(xmlParser);
        stream.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
 public static List<Item> getNews(){
    if(items==null)
        return null;
    List<Item> news=new ArrayList<Item>();
    for(Item item:items){
        if("news_section".equals(item.getType()))
            news.add(item);
    }
    return news;
}// for the rest of the data, there are other methods
`
```

This is one of the fragments that displays the data

```
 public class HomeActivity extends Fragment{
    static ListView newsList;
    static Item item=null;//list of Item objects
        static Context context;
    static ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    static AllItems articles=new AllItems();
        static List<Item> news=new ArrayList<Item>();
    static int i=0;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   //newsList=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.news_list);
  // itemAdapter=new ItemAdapter(context,typeOfNew,(ArrayList<Item>)news);
 //  newsList.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity, container,false);    
}

public static void displayNews(List<Item> news){
    try {        
         if(news==null || news.size()==0){
                //Retrieve again the data list
         }
         //Log.d("HomeActivity","total news: "+news.size());
         for(Item item:news){ //Item is the object that I'm using to create the List
             news.get(i);
             i++;
             itemAdapter.add(news.get(i));
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

And in the main Activity I only execute the AsyncTask in the OnCreateView() with this line
    parser.execute();

I've read that I can use Handlers so the data Thread can communicate with the UI Thread, but I'm lost. I have a total of 6 fragments in where i'd like to display the data, and all the fragments are initialized from the MainActivity.I added several log.d to visualize how the app is working, and all the fragments are created before the AsynTask finishes processing the data. Please help, any information will be appreciated, if you need more info or code, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main Activity, create member variables for each of your Fragments, ie.

```
private FragmentA fragmentA;
private FragmentB fragmentB;
```

In the Fragment classes, define a setter for the data:

```
public void setListItems(List<Item> listItems) {
    // Code for updating the Fragment UI components here
}
```

Once the AsyncTask completes, from the main Activity, call

```
this.fragmentA.setListItems(dataForA);
this.fragmentB.setListItems(dataForB);
....
```

You probably need to have the AsyncTask report that it is finished to the main activity in the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Where would I be calling `this.fragmentA.setListItems(dataForA);`, from the onCreate() in MainActivity?? When I call this method from the Main it says "the Method setListItem is undefined for the type fragment." What I want to do or what I'm trying is kinda like interrupt or pause the onCreateView in the different fragments, so they can receive the data and then update the ListView in the UI.

Comment: `setListItems` is undefined for type `Fragment` -- but you are extending `Fragment`, and calling it `HomeActivity`, for example. Inside `HomeActivity`, declare `setListItems` as a member function. Inside main Activity, add a member variable `private HomeActivity homeActivityFragment`. Then you will be able to call `homeActivityFragment.setListItems`

Comment: As for where to call it from: you should probably allow all of the `onCreate` methods to run without interrupting them, since getting data from a url is a long process that should be done in the background. But _after_ the process finishes, that's the time to populate the fragments with data. From `onPostExecute` you could call a method in your main Activity that will do `setListItems` for each fragment.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to display the content, I created the method `setListItems()`, called the `setAdapter()` to my `ListView` in that method, and I sent the data from my `AsyncTask`. Many many thanks.